# iPhone hardware capabilities : magnetometer and gyro

Tags: iphone, hardware, motion, gyroscope, magnetometer

Can someone tell me, for any iPhone that have been sold, if they are equiped with a gyro and a magnetometer ?

As a complement, do you know a website that gives a comparative table of hardware capabilities of any iPhone sold ? (By iPhone I mean any iDevice that has telephony capability, in the sense of "Required device capabilities" = "telephony" plist key. Perhaps other than iPhone could do that ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia knows all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#iPhone) The [main iPhone page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) also lists the technologies as they were added.

Comment: I don't see any reference to the magnetometer... and just a poor reference to the 4 proximity sensors of the iPhone 4. That does not seem to be a complete reference, don't you think ?

Comment: The magnetometer is under 3GS as digital compass.

Answer (score 0):

I found the table and all the wanted references here (french Wikipedia iPhone page) :

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone#Caract.C3.A9ristiques_techniques